# A nonlinear initial-boundary value problems with Taylor expansion of parameter

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, sequences-and-series, taylor-series

Let $u(x,t; \epsilon)$ satisfy the nonlinear initial boundary value problem 
$$
u_{tt} = (u_{x} + u_{x}^3)_{x} + u_{xxt}, \space 0 \lt x \lt 1
$$
$$
u(0,t) = 0 \\
u(1,t) = 0 \\
u(x,0) = \epsilon f(x) \\
u_{t}(x,0) = \epsilon g(x)
$$
where $f(0) = 0 = f(1)$ and $g(0) = 0 = g(1)$. How do I go about finding the equation satisfied by $u$ if I assume that the solution depends smoothly on $\epsilon$ in the neighborhood of $0$, so that $u$ has the beginnings of a Taylor expansion in $\epsilon:$ 
$\\\\ u(x,t; \epsilon) = 0 + u_{1}(x,t)\epsilon + \frac{1}{2}u_{2}(x,t)\epsilon^2 + \frac{1}{3}u_{3}(x,t)\epsilon^3 + \space...\space + \frac{1}{n}u_{n}(x,t)\epsilon^n $

And is it possible to prove that such a solution is unique? Also, regarding notation, does $(u_{x} + u_{x}^3)_{x}$ signify the partial derivative of $(u_{x} + u_{x}^3)$ with respect to x? Is this equivalent to $u_{xx} + (u_{x}^3)_{x}$?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510648/nonlinear-initial-boundary-value-problems-using-taylor-expansion-of-parameter

Answer (score 1):

The technique to solve this problem, as suggested by the formulation of the question, is perturbation theory. One writes the solution in the form
$$
   u(x,t)=\epsilon u_1(x,t)+ \epsilon^2 u_2(x,t)+\epsilon^3 u_3(x,t)+\ldots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon^n u_n(x,t)
$$
and put this into the equation and the initial and boundary conditions. In this case one gets the set of non-trivial equations
$$
     u_{1tt}=u_{1xx}+u_{1xxt}
$$
with $u_1(0,t)=u_1(1,t)=0$, $u_1(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_{1t}(x,0)=g(x)$. This equation is linear and can be solved with standard techniques. Then, at second order one has
$$
    u_{2tt}=u_{2xx}+u_{2xxt}
$$
with $u_2(0,t)=u_2(1,t)=0$, $u_2(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_{2t}(x,0)=g(x)$ and so, $u_2=0$ the trivial solution. At the third order one has a non-trivial equation
$$
    u_{3tt}=u_{3xx}+u_{3xxt}+(u_{1x}^3)_x
$$
that has a non-null solution and the solution can be given using the Green function of the linear equation. From this, you can iterate to whatever order you want.